# PHP/MYSQL - Retrieving Multiple Results and Creating Arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I currently have a database containing a set of data that I need to retrieve and turn into a JSON array.

The database is structured like so:

```
Table: Rank
-----------
id - word - date - rank
```

At the moment I have it working so that the PHP code retrieves the data relating to a specific word and correctly turns it into a JSON array. 
This is my code:

```
public function getMain() {
    $v1 = "word1";
    $v2 = "word2";
    try{                 
        $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM rank WHERE word = ?");
        $query->bindValue(1, $v1); 
        $query->execute();    

        while($row = $query->fetch()) {
            $test = $row[2];
            $test = str_replace("/", "-", $test);                            
            $data['label'] = $row[1];
            $data['data'][] = array($test, $row[3]);
        } 

        $json = json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);                            
        echo $json;

    }catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

The output of the above is as follows:

```
{
    "label":"word1",
    "data":[
        ["25-07-2014",3],
        ["26-07-2014",4],
        ["27-07-2014",5]
    ]
}
```

The above output matches exactly how I need it returned.

However, I need to run this for multiple words and still get the same output structure for each word. As you can see in my code above, I have 2 variables: "$v1" and "$v2", each with a unique word. I need to run this query and return the results for both of these words and get the following output (based on the DB data of course):

```
{
    "label":"word1",
    "data":[
        ["25-07-2014",3],
        ["26-07-2014",4],
        ["27-07-2014",5]
    ]
}
{
    "label":"word2",
    "data":[
        ["25-07-2014",1],
        ["26-07-2014",2],
        ["27-07-2014",8]
    ]
}
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Store the values in array and run it in the query..

```
$values = array("a","b","b");
foreach($values as $value)
{
    $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM rank WHERE word = $value");
    $query->bindValue(1, $v1); 

    $query->execute();    

    while($row = $query->fetch()) {
        $test = $row[2];
        $test = str_replace("/", "-", $test);

        $data['label'] = $row[1];
        $data['data'][] = array($test, $row[3]);
    } 

    $json = json_encode($data, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);

    echo $json;  
    data[] = $json;
}
```

The data contains all the results produced by the query....